# Order by is not working in wordpress custom query in custom post type

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, repeater

I am using ACF Pro Repeater field and my custom field name in database is seminars_details_0_start_date, seminars_details_1_start_date and so on

Here is the code I am using

```
function my_posts_where( $where ) {
            $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'seminars_details_$", "meta_key LIKE 'seminars_details_%", $where);
            return $where;
          }
          add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');
          $args = array(
           // 'numberposts' => ,
            'posts_per_page'=> '-1',
            'post_type'   => 'training',
            'meta_key'      => 'seminars_details_$_start_date',
            'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
            'order'       => 'DESC',
            'meta_query'  => array(
              'relation'    => 'OR',
             array(
                'key'   => 'seminars_details_$_start_date',
                'value'   => array('20230101'  , '20231231'),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
              ),
            )
          );

          $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all there are a few defects in your code. try replacing the $args with below code-

```
$args = array(
            

        // 'numberposts' => ,
                'posts_per_page'=> -1,   // number cannot be in quotes 
                'post_type'   => 'property',
                'meta_query'  => array(
                  
                   'custom_sort'=> array(
                   'key'   => 'seminars_details_$_start_date',
                    'value'   => array('20230101'  , '20231231'),
                    'type'    => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                    
                   ),
                   ),
            'order_by'=>array(
                        'custom_sort'=>'DESC',
                        ),
              );
```

Comment: It's still not working for me.

Comment: Can you share your acf page screenshot here?

Comment: Here is the screenshot link: tinyurl.com/2e5mt5cb
I have created a Seminars Details repeater field. And want to sort posts based on Start Date Field.

Comment: Hi in the acf screenshot i can see that you have added the repeater feilds to a post type property but in your code you are passing training.

Comment: Once you have figured out which post type you want to use. Try it with my edited code. One more thing i could not see in the screenshot what type of data type your start_date is returning whether it is a date or number. If number does not work please replace the 'type'=>'numeric' to 'date'